# Sum code not working properly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to redirect from www.domain1.com to www.domain2.com getting the actual domain name.

Let's say that our page is www.domain1.com:

```
  var domainName = window.location.host;
  var domainNumber =  domainName.substr(10, 1);
  var finalDomain = (domainNumber+1);
```

If I print `finalDomain` on the screen, I got **11**. So because of that my redirect is not working.
How do I do `domainNumber` plus **1**, so I got **2** and not **11**?

Comment: This has nothing to do with domains or redirects. It's a question about taking a numeric string and applying `+1`.

Answer (score 0):

`substr` method will return you a string, not a number. so you are getting `"1"` , not `1`

when you do `"1"+1`, you will get `"11"`

use `parseInt()` method to convert `"1"` to `1` before the addition operation.

```
var finalDomain = parseInt(domainNumber)+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick [parseInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53yedee(v=vs.94).aspx):

> Converts a string to an integer.

```
var finalDomain = parseInt(domainNumber) + 1;
```

The issue you are having is because in javascript "1" + 1 is "11". So, you need to convert the string "1" to int in order to add it 1 afterwards.

Test it yourself here:

```js
alert("1" + 1 === "11")

alert(1 + 1 === 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`domainNumber` is a string, not a number, so when you add 1, you're actually concatenating the string "1" onto the end of a string "1" to make "11". You need to convert it into a number using the parseInt() function, as follows:

`var domainNumber = parseInt(domainName.substr(10, 1), 10);`

Note: The second parameter passed to parseInt() signifies that the string is in decimal (base 10). Now domainNumber is a number rather than a string, so if you try to add one to it you'll get 2.

`var finalDomain` will be a number, unless you set it to be a string by calling toString():

`var finalDomain = (domainNumber + 1).toString()` - If you do this, finalDomain will be a string containing the value "2".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var domainName = window.location.host;
var domainNumber =  domainName.substr(10, 1);
domainNumber = parseInt(domainNumber);
var finalDomain = (domainNumber+1);
```

u need to parse ur domainNumber variable to integer type in order to do addition.
see here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: I'm downvoting this because (a) you link to w3schools, and (b) you put such a disrespectful lack of effort into writing your answer. "u"? "ur"? Seriously?